# how to make an HTML widget "follow" remain sight, as the user scrolls up and down the page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

In my AngularJS app, I have the following text area widget:

```
<div class="col-md-4" style="padding-top: 30px">
        <div class="ibox float-e-margins">
            <div class="ibox-title">
                <h5>Proposed Updates for Subject Area:   {{selectedSubjectArea}}</h5>

                <div ibox-tools></div>
            </div>
            <div class="ibox-content">
                <form role="form" class="form-inline">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <textarea class="form-control" rows="4" cols="127" data-ng-model="proposedChanges">
                        </textarea>
                    </div>
                    <button class="btn btn-white" type="submit" data-ng-click="submitChanges()">Submit</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

What are the CSS attributes, which would "make" this widget follow the line of sight, and remain visible, as the user scrolls the page up or down?

Comment: Maybe look into `position: fixed`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.ibox{
    position:fixed;
    bottom:30px;
    right:20px;
  
  /*just for the preview*/
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background:silver;
}

.wrap{height:700px;}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.<br><br><br><br>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</div>

<div class="ibox"></div>
```

this will put the object to the bottom right. You will need to play with the bottom and right px to accommodate your object's size.

```
.ibox{
    position:fixed;
    bottom:30px;
    right:20px;
}
```

Comment: I now have it exactly as suggested, but that does not force this widget to "follow" the page scroll. It simply pushes it to the bottom of the page. I expect this widget to always remain within the visible part of the page, so when the page is scrolled, the widget would follow, and change its position to remain visible.

Comment: I updated my answer with a working example of my code, is that what you were expecting?

Comment: You mean it should be with position:absolute; but then scroll with the user if the element reaches the border of the window?